# Antlr4 Parsing dates

Tags: date, antlr4

I am trying to parse a date using Antlr4 with C# as a target. A valid date in my case should have the following

- be in `year / month / day` format
- year MUST have only 4 digits
- month and day MUST have only 2 digits

I know that similar questions are already here, but their solutions does not seem to work for me

- [How to create a antlr4 grammar which will parse date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651518/how-to-create-a-antlr4-grammar-which-will-parse-date)
- [Antlr: Simplest way to recognize dates and numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141875/antlr-simplest-way-to-recognize-dates-and-numbers)

I have read somewhere that there is a priority-like parsing, where top-most rules based on how the grammar file is written are evaluated first. So consider that apart from dates my grammar should also be able to parse integers.

The grammar I have and works (but it does not follow the aforementioned rules is the following)

```
/*
 *  Parser Rules
 */

dateFormat :  DECIMAL '/' DECIMAL '/' DECIMAL
   ;

/*
 *  Lexer Rules
 */

DECIMAL:            DEC_DIGIT+;

fragment DEC_DIGIT:    [0-9];
```

I tried to put something like

> YEAR or year : DEC_DIGIT DEC_DIGIT DEC_DIGIT DEC_DIGIT;

in either lexer or parser rules but it did not work.

Any ideas / suggestions ?

**Note:** Please do not suggest alternatives of regex or argue on whenever I should use Antlr or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this should work. `date` parse rule for dates, `integer` rule for integers.

```
date
    : year=FOUR_DIGITS SLASH month=TWO_DIGITS SLASH day=TWO_DIGITS
    ;

integer
    : INTEGER
    | FOUR_DIGITS
    | TWO_DIGITS
    ;

FOUR_DIGITS: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
TWO_DIGITS:  DIGIT DIGIT;
INTEGER:     DIGIT+;
SLASH:       '/';

fragment     DIGIT: [0-9];
```

Comment: I do not know if this is the case but in my example the integer (aka DECIMAL) is defined as a lexer rule and not as parser

Comment: Lexer is not able to count chars. If we want to have lexer DECIMAL rule we should also have integer parse rule for handling FOUR_DIGITS and TWO_DIGITS (they used in date parse rule).

Comment: FYI I just tested my assumption that `top-most rules based on how the grammar file is written are evaluated first`. If I change you grammar and put the `INTEGER` lexer rule, before the `FOUR_DIGITS` rule, the grammar will fail to parse the dates.